# Logging from 2 root logger to 1 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have a function for quickly setting up the logger:

```
def init_logger(name: str, log_path: str):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    cli_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    cli_handler.setFormatter(CLILoggerFormatter())
    cli_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(cli_handler)

    file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_path, when="midnight", encoding="utf-8")
    file_handler.setFormatter(FileLoggerFormatter())
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Also, my python package `my_lib` has these lines of code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

And this is the `main.py` file

```
import my_lib
import logging

init_logger(__name__, "logs/log.log")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
init_logger("my_lib", "logs/log.log")
```

By design, all logs from the python package `my_lib` and from the `main.py` file should be written to 1 file `log.log` (which changes every midnight). But at midnight an error is thrown:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 74, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 435, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 115, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is occupied by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Woopertail\\Desktop\\Test\\logs\\log.log' -> 'C:\\Users\\Woopertail\\Desktop\\Test\\logs\\log.log.2022-11-23'
```

As far as I understand, this happens because 2 root loggers are trying to create and open a file one after another, and the second one gets an error like this.

Is there any way to make 2 root loggers save records to 1 file?

Comment: @wim oh, ye, it is.

Comment: IMO doing the log rotation from within Python is sort of dumb, I usually prefer to just make Python log to stdout/stderr (i.e. use `logging.basicConfig`) and then give the redirect/file handling to something more purpose-built such as [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: @wim, but if I run it on Windows?

Comment: [Here's a nickel, kid. Get yourself a better computer.](https://dilbert.com/strip/1995-06-24)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, here's a solution that helped me.

Instead of adding a handler to each logger object, I used `logging.config.dictConfig`:

```
import logging
import logging.config


CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "handlers": {
        "file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "file_formatter",
            "filename": "logs/log.log",
            "when": "midnight",
            "encoding": "utf-8"
        },

        "cli_handler": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "cli_formatter"
        }
    },

    "formatters": {
        "file_formatter": {
            "()": "MyFormatters.FileLoggerFormatter"
        },

        "cli_formatter": {
            "()": "MyFormatters.CLILoggerFormatter"
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "main": {
            "handlers": ["file_handler", "cli_handler"],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        },
        "my_lib": {
            "handlers": ["file_handler", "cli_handler"],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(CONFIG)
logger = logging.getLogger("main")
```